# Keras model (even during training) only predicts 0

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras

Im trying to train a keras image classifier to predict between weeds(1) and grasses(0) in images. However, whatever method/model i try to build, the accuracy gets stuck, and by that I mean the training accuracy is as if it is only predicting 0s. i can confirm this, because when I changed my labels array to contain only zeros, the model somehow claimed 1.00 accuracy, but when I changed the labels all to ones, the model accuracy was 0.00. All my images are scaled and converted to rgb.
heres the code:

```
def prep_image(filename):
  im = cv2.imread(filename, 0)
  new_im = cv2.resize(im, (400,530))
  arr = np.array(new_im)
  arr = np.reshape(arr, (530, 400))
  return arr

image_files = [] #contains the file paths of the images
images = [] # contains arrays/images
labels = []
n_classes = 2
def add_image_data(root):
  global images
  global labels
  print("starting")
  delim = os.sep

  for dirpath, dirs, files in tqdm(os.walk(root)): 
    for file in [f for f in files if (f.endswith(".jpg"))]:
      image_files.append(os.path.join(dirpath, file))

  for file in tqdm(image_files):
    image_arr = prep_image(file)
    images.append(image_arr)
    #print("supposed added ", file)
    label = file.split(delim)[-2]
    if label == "Grass":
      label = 0;
    else:
      label = 1;
    labels.append(label)

  images = np.array(images)
  labels = np.array(labels)
```

I then apply to_categorical(labels) to one-hot encode them
model:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(32, kernel_size=3, input_shape=(530, 400, 1)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Conv2D(32, kernel_size=3))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Conv2D(64, kernel_size=3))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(64))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
#model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(2)) #or n_clasess
model.add(Activation('softmax'))

model.compile(optimizer=Adam(0.0001), loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
```

there also does not seem to be any learning taking place, the loss and the accuracy seems to get stuck after the first epoch. the labels contain both classes.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Since you have only 2 classes, you should use `loss='binary_crossentropy'`; I would also suggest leaving your last dense layer with only 1 unit and `sigmoid` activation (do you currently one-hot encode your labels?)

Comment: @desertnaut I have tried that also, but same result, i have been switching between the two models and both give the same outputs. I have also tried binary crossentropy with 1 unit and sigmoid, but that also did not work

Comment: Such details are always useful to include in the question...

Comment: Also include what you're calling to train the model. I assume `model.fit` but include it to be complete. Also, by "all my images are scaled" do you mean resized? Are you doing any normalization that we don't see? Some visualization of the data would be helpful. And, for future reference, you don't need to convert an image to an array since `cv2` will use NumPy as its representation of images.

Comment: @LukeDeLuccia i assumed greyscale to be automatic normalization, but I have fixed the issue now, by manually normlizing. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you looked at your predictions scores? If the accuracy metric is based an a prediction score of > 0.5, it could be that none of your classes are actually given a score larger than 0.5. This is probably due to class imbalance. You can then change the threshold for a "positive" prediction.

Try to use a metric such as AUC instead, or just print out your predictions and examine the scores.

Edit from comments:
Have you preprocessed your inputs properly? Normalization etc. If your input values are too big, gradients will not flow properly.

The lack of normalization will stop the gradient flow. This is due to the fact that you will not make use of the non-linearity in the activation functions if your values are too big/small for all inputs.

Comment: Have you preprocessed your inputs properly? Normalization etc. If your input values are too big, gradients will not flow properly.

Comment: This works, I simply assumed because it was greyscale that it was normalised, but it wasnt, now it is training, Thanks!, update answer so i can accept

Answer (score 0):

Is your dataset unbalanced ? This is a common problem when you have a heavily unbalanced dataset. This means that one or more of the classes and way more frequent than the others. Your model have found that the easiest way to achieve a considerable accuracy is to guess the most frequent class. This can make the learning optimization way harder.

There are several ways to deal with unbalanced datasets that you can try: https://machinelearningmastery.com/tactics-to-combat-imbalanced-classes-in-your-machine-learning-dataset/

Comment: would 70-30 % count as heavily unbalanced?, and as i mentioned, even when i made my labels all zeros or all ones, it either made the acc 0 or 1, so i think the problem might be something else

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem may be that you are comparing a label ( 0 or 1 ) with the result of softmax that is two values representing the probability of the subject to be for that class.

You should do a one-hot encoding converting like this:
0 -> [1, 0]
1 -> [0, 1]

This way the output of the neural network and the labels are in the same format and can be compared.

Comment: my bad, i forgot to add the code for that, but i do use to_categorical to one hot encode my labels